# An EF Core transaction on the other DbContext isn't disposed after the original one is when using UseTransaction

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, sqltransaction

Here's an interesting behavior I ran into the other day. I'm using EF Core's `UseTransaction` method to share a transaction with another `DbContext`. The problem I ran into was that the other context would **keep the transaction even after the original transaction was disposed** and that caused some unexpected bugs. What's more, the issue only seems to occur when using SQLite, SQL Server works fine.

Here's a shorter version of what the app is doing:

```cs
var connectionString = $"Data Source={Guid.NewGuid()};Mode=Memory;Cache=Shared";
var keepAliveConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
keepAliveConnection.Open();

var dbContext1 = new DbContext1(
    new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext1>()
        .UseSqlite(connectionString)
        .Options);

var dbContext2 = new DbContext2(
    new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext2>()
        .UseSqlite(dbContext1.Database.GetDbConnection())
        .Options);

using (var transaction = dbContext1.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    dbContext2.Database.UseTransaction(transaction.GetDbTransaction());

    // ... do some work

    await transaction.CommitAsync();
}

Debug.Assert(dbContext2.Database.CurrentTransaction is null); // this fails
```

And here's the exception I get:

```
The transaction object is not associated with the same connection object as this command.

at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(Enumerator enumerator)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<>c.<MoveNext>b__19_0(DbContext _, Enumerator enumerator)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.NonRetryingExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetSingle[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Boolean& found)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
at System.Linq.Queryable.Single[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
at Company.DomainEvents.Services.GenericDomainEventService`4.UpdateEventStatus(Guid eventId, PublisherEventState status) in C:\Repos\domainevents\src\Company.DomainEvents\Services\GenericDomainEventService.cs:line 198
at Company.DomainEvents.Services.GenericDomainEventService`4.MarkEventAsInProgress(Guid eventId) in C:\Repos\domainevents\src\Company.DomainEvents\Services\GenericDomainEventService.cs:line 192
at Company.DomainEvents.Services.GenericDomainEventService`4.<PublishDomainEvent>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\Repos\domainevents\src\Company.DomainEvents\Services\GenericDomainEventService.cs:line 112
```

**Fix / workaround**

Disposing the transaction returned by `dbContext2.Database.UseTransaction` seems to do the trick. Though I'm not very confident it's the correct solution... To fix the problem, I only modified one line from:

```cs
dbContext2.Database.UseTransaction(transaction.GetDbTransaction());
```

to this:

```cs
using var _ = dbContext2.Database.UseTransaction(transaction.GetDbTransaction());
```

Now the other context's transaction will be disposed as well as the original one.